# how do I make a bbcode to parse url tags into links?

Tags: php, html, css, bbcode

How should I go about parsing a url in php? I wanna make it so it goes

```
[url=http://www.google.com]Google[/url]
```

Turns into:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
```

This is the code I'm using for my other bb codes:

```
function postparser($post){ 
        $post = str_replace("\n",'END_OF_LINE',$post);

        $post = str_replace("[line]",'HORIZONTAL_LINE',$post);

        $post = str_replace("[bold]",'BOLD_TEXT_START',$post);
        $post = str_replace("[/bold]",'BOLD_TEXT_END',$post);

        $post = str_replace("[yt]",'YOUTUBE_START',$post);
        $post = str_replace("[/yt]",'YOUTUBE_END',$post);

        $post = sanitize($post);

        $post = str_replace("END_OF_LINE",'<br />',$post);

        $post = str_replace("HORIZONTAL_LINE",'<hr />',$post);

        $post = str_replace("BOLD_TEXT_START",'<b>',$post);
        $post = str_replace("BOLD_TEXT_END",'</b>',$post);

        $post = str_replace("YOUTUBE_START",'<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/',$post);
        $post = str_replace("YOUTUBE_END",'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>',$post);

        return $post;
    }
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: If wanting to parse `[url]` tags with and without the double quoted url in the opening tag, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50198746/2943403).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$post = preg_replace('/\[url=(.+?)\](.+?)\[\/url\]/', '<a href="\1">\2</a>', $post);
```

That will turn:
    [url=http://google.com]Google[/url]

Into parsed bbcode text:
    [Google](http://google.com)

You'll probably want to use more specific [regex](http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/) than just **.+** to filter out potentially bad/dangerous input.

Comment: It is a bad solution... I can add to my url somethink like this for add XSS:

[url=http://google.com" onclick="myfucnk();"]Google[/url] or [url=javascript: alert('XSS!');]Google[/url]