# PHP Replacing HREF link with BBCODE URL

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Pulling my hair out on this.  I am parsing text and I need to convert any href links to bbcode URL instead.  Example:

```
<a href="http://www.foo.com" rel="nofollow">http://www.foo.com</a>
```

Here is my PHP code:

```
$str = preg_replace('#(<a href=[\'"])(.*?)([\'"]>)(.*?)(</a>)#', '[URL=$2]$4[/URL]', $str);
```

No matter what I try to do, the best I can get is this:

```
[URL=http://www.foo.com" rel="nofollow]http://www.foo.com[/URL]
```

I have tried this too:

```
$str = preg_replace('#(<a href=[\'"])(.*?)([\'"]>)([^\'"].*?)(</a>)#', '[URL=$2]$4[/URL]', $str);
```

Nothing works.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900385/how-do-i-make-a-bbcode-to-parse-url-tags-into-links

Comment: @BiGGiE0344 That's the exact opposite of this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One more wildcard does the trick for that regex - you need to allow for the extra characters between the closing `"` and the `>`:

```
$str = preg_replace('#(<a href=[\'"])(.*?)([\'"].*>)(.*?)(</a>)#', '[URL=$2]$4[/URL]', $str);
```

Depending on your data, you might also want to consider other possible combinations, for example of the link looks like `<a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.foo.com">http://www.foo.com</a>`:

```
$str = preg_replace('#(<a\s.*href=[\'"])(.*?)([\'"].*>)(.*?)(</a>)#', '[URL=$2]$4[/URL]', $str);
```

Answer (score -1):

An example with DOMDocument:

```
$html = '<div><a href="http://www.foo.com" rel="nofollow">http://www.foo.com</a></div>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD | LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);
$nodeList = $dom->getElementsByTagName("a");
$linkArr = [];
foreach ($nodeList as $link) { $linkArr[] = $link; }
foreach ($linkArr as $link) {
    $text = "[URL=" . $link->getAttribute("href") . "]"
          . $link->nodeValue . "[/URL]";
    $link->parentNode->replaceChild($dom->createTextNode($text), $link);
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't seem to work.  $dom->saveHTML(); seemed to return nothing.